# How to pass arguments into an outside module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I have the following function that I placed inside a separate js file.

I am trying to use it inside another javascript file that requires passport.js, and I would like to call it using `app.use` to further modularize my application

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET welcome page. */
router.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'title',
        user : req.user
    });
});


// route middleware to make sure
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

The reason I created it is so I reduce redundancy and not use the following code each time:

```
app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('home.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. is authenticated is undefined although it is in the same folder, and it gives me an error 404 not found when I issue a get. How I can keep it in an external file and still use it? should I also pass it the `user` argument from where I am calling it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = function (app, passport){

router.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
res.render('home', {
    title: 'title',
    user : req.user
  });
});

return router;
};

 function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

// if user is logged in - 
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

// if they aren't redirect them to home
res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have one question how do I call it then from the other js file? like this? : app.use('/home', home);

Comment: `require('./models/routes.js')(app, passport);`

Comment: ReferenceError: home is not defined

Comment: You don't have the slightest idea of what you're doing, isn't it so? Please delete `app.use('/home', home);`.

Comment: Im actually quite new to this. I deleted it, but when I require it's still giving me a 404 error

Comment: Are you requiring it after setting up passport? Try placing it at the end of the file. Post your 'app.js' here if this doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109991/discussion-between-predator44-and-noideawhattodo).